# Bootstrap datetimepicker shows week from next month

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart, datetimepicker

[Calendar with extra unwanted week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LASsA.png)Have bootstrap-datetimepicker included in OpenCart installation. I have tweaked and styled it a bit.

Problem: it shows present month PLUS one week of next (see attached screen shot). What I'd like is that the calendar shows present month WITHOUT that first week of next month.

Have gone through the bootstrap-datetimepicker.js file but can't find a way to fix this.

Since the file (bootstrap-datetimepicker.js) is too vast to be copied here, I have made it available at https://proformica.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker.zip

Any suggestion will be much appreciated!

Dan

Comment: BTW (sorry, I'm a newbie here): if anyone knows how to COMPLETELY hide everything (i.e. weeks/days next or previous month) from displaying, that would be fantastic! I.e. to display ONLY the dates of the selected month...

Answer (score 0):

Try the configuration option:

```
showOtherMonths: false,
```

i.e.

```
$('#your-selector').datepicker();
   showOtherMonths: false
});
```

You can try this out in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/scottcwilson/fzavjdh5/1/